# DB design for multiple different objects

Tags: database-design

I'm working on an application where users can write tests using blocks. Blocks are commands (like `assign`, `for`, `if` etc.) so some of the blocks can also contain other blocks.
We're using the composite pattern - there's an `abstract block` and `leaf` & `composite` block classes (also abstract), and the concrete blocks inherit from the relevant class (`if` block is composite, `assign` block is a leaf).
We used to serialize the entire test and save it as a blob, but we're considering changing that (to enable search inside the test, for example).
So how should the DB design look like? Should I have a table for each object? In our case, it will mean around 30 tables. Should we include the block's type as a column? This means we'll have a huge `if-else` switch somewhere.
I'd appreciate your insights and suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a table for each *kind* of object.  Multiple instances of the same kind should be stored in multiple rows of the same table, with different data used to distinguish them from each other.

The question of whether two objects are or are not of the same kind can be subtle one, especially in the case you outline.  Here's my suggestion.  Do an Object Oriented Analysis of all the objects you intend to deal with.  Be careful to distinguish between  Object Oriented Analysis and Object Oriented Design.  Consult a textbook if you need to.  Peter Coad wrote some good books on OOA some twenty years ago.

Convert the OOA model to an ER model,  dropping behavior out of the mix, and keeping only data.  Keep the OOA model around, because it will be useful to have when you go to design the software.  ER models can accomodate a gen-spec pattern, so use this feature if you have classes and subclasses of objects in your model.  In your case, you will.

Then convert your  ER model to a relational model, in preparation for converting the relational model into a series of SQL data definition scripts.  Classes and subclasses get messy at this point, because the relational model doesn't have inheritance built in.  Consult tutorials on what is called "Class Table Inheritance".  There are plenty of answers to CTI questions here in SO.

If you do CTI properly, you won't need the object type  (class) as a separate field, but you can include it (denormalization) if it will speed things up.  I generally don't do that unless it becomes necessary.